# How to move up the rigth tableofcontents?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have a problem with a memoir class. The tableofcontents is on left but i want it to right with a more white space on left. I use the memoir class and the option `openright` but i don't understand as resolve this problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openleft]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{setspace}

\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth} 
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth} 
\settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*} 
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5} 
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout
%
\frenchspacing
% Font with math support: New Century Schoolbook
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\OnehalfSpacing 
%
% Sets numbering division level
\setsecnumdepth{subsection} 
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
%
\usepackage{calc,soul,fourier}
\makeatletter 
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw 
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth} 
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter} 
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{% 
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
            \colorbox{gray}{\color{white}\thechapter}% 
        }}%
        \rotatebox{90}{% 
            \resizebox{%
                \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}% 
            {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
        \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
} 
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}% 
    \makebox[0pt][c]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
    }}
\makechapterstyle{daleifmodif}{
    \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so} 
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\scshape} 
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{} \renewcommand\printchaptername{} 
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par} 
    \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip} 
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\color{gray}\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
} 
\makeatother 
\chapterstyle{daleifmodif}
%
% The pages should be numbered consecutively at the bottom centre of the
% page.
\makepagestyle{myvf} 
\makeoddfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeevenfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeheadrule{myvf}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 
\makeevenhead{myvf}{\small\textsc{\leftmark}}{}{} 
\makeoddhead{myvf}{}{}{\small\textsc{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{myvf}
%
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\doublepage}}
%
\makeindex

\usepackage{lipsum}                     \usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{color}                                  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
             allcolors=black]{hyperref}             
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 


\begin{document}

 \pagenumbering{gobble} 

 \begin{titlingpage}
\begin{SingleSpace}
\calccentering{\unitlength} 
\begin{adjustwidth*}{\unitlength}{-\unitlength}
\begin{center}
{\Large \textit{AAA}}\\
\vspace{6 mm}
\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{2pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{3.2pt}
\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\HUGE BB }\\[4mm]
{\Large \textit{AAA}}\\
\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{2pt}\\
\vspace{20.5mm}

\vspace{6cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Studente:}\\

\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Docenti:} \\

\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3.5cm]
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
{\small aa}
\end{flushright}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{SingleSpace}
\end{titlingpage}

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
   % indice
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    \listoftables
    \newpage

    \begingroup


      \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{} 
      \renewcommand{\clearpage}{} 

      \titleformat{\chapter}
        {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}

      \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0in}{0.2in}
      \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.20in}{0.1in}
      \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.10in}{0.02in}
  \mainmatter

\chapter{1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{2} 
\lipsum[2-3]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of program]

This figure show a problem: too margin on right then left

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Do you want the margin on the left increased only for the index of figures or for the whole document?

Comment: Solo per indice. Il margine dell'altra parte del documento è ok, ma l'indice n. Se faccio un binding la posizione dell'indice è errata

Comment: @Zenzu The language of the site is English. You're using “index”, but it should be “table of contents”. Please, make a minimal example, removing all that's unnecessary. By the way, typesetting the whole document inside a group is not really a good idea.

Comment: Sorry for my imprecision. I mean tableofcontens. In my work i separate the document in chapter but for this post i make a unique document.

Comment: You are using the option `openleft`, so your chapters start on even pages. But your TOC will be on page ``i``, an odd page number, and uses the geometry of odd pages. You can precede it with `\null\clearpage`, so it will be start on page ``ii``. It is not clear though if you want it to have equal margins or the margins of even pages. Besides `\renewcommand\clearpage{}` is just very very bad idea. You seem to be badly mistreating the class, why do you use at all the `twoside` option ?

Comment: Ok, i solve this problem with `\null\clearpage`. My problem was start tableofcontens on right because it is on page `iii` and I needed this position on page "front on right page `i`-back on left page `ii`-front on right (tableofcontents) page `iii`". I hope I have been clearer now. Thanks